# How to correctly use fminsearch in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to translate a part of my matlab code in python. Actually I'm looking for how to translate `fminsearch` and I found it on this website with this example :

```
import scipy.optimize

banana = lambda x: 100*(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2+(1-x[0])**2
xopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[-1.2,1])
```

My first question is how to return also the value of `fmin` ?

And in my code when I type :

```
banana = lambda X: diff_norm(X, abst0, ord0);
Xu = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, X)
```

Python answered me :

```
Xu = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, X)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I don't understand why Python told me that because what i want to do is to minimize the function `diff_norm` changing the values of `X`, i precise `X` is an array of length 10.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python told you that because in Python, keyword arguments always follow non keyword (i.e positional) arguments (keyword args have a name assigned to them, as in `func` in the `fmin` call). Your function call should look like:

```
Xu = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=X)
```

in order to comply with *[Python's calling conventions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)*. Alternatively, and, according to the [function definition of `fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy-optimize-fmin), you could only supply positional arguments for these two first arguments:

```
Xu = scipy.optimize.fmin(banana, X)
```

this will return the values that minimize the function, so, just call the function providing these arguments:

```
minval = banana(Xu)
```

Alternatively you could call `fmin` with `full_output = True` and get a tuple of elements back, the second element of that tuple is the minimum value:

```
_, minval, *_ = scipy.optimize.fmin(banana, X, full_output=True)
```

Now `minval` contains your full output.